# How do I use proxies with OpenURI?

Tags: ruby, proxy, open-uri

I'm trying to crawl a site but I need proxies to be used in order to not be banned.

```
proxies.each do |proxy|
  proxy.delete '""'
  break if @doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(pre, :proxy => proxy )) rescue nil
end
```

I have a list of working proxies in the `proxies` array. `pre` is the URL. I have no response from this code, just nil. If I replace this with the code below, it works but it has the risk of an IP ban:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(pre))
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you share the array `proxies`? How does it look like?

Comment: I'm sure it is in the format 'ip:port'

Comment: Nokogiri doesn't care about proxies or know about HTTP so this question shouldn't even mention it. The problem is with your use of OpenURI. Reduce your sample code until Nokogiri is out of the question and the problem will remain. Rewrite your question to accurately reflect the code and problem at that point. As is, your question just shows you don't know how your code works.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is somewhere in the definition of your proxies. Unfortunately, because you didn't show us a complete example of your code, we can't help you there.

The proper definition is documented: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI/OpenRead.html

Comment: Thank you, I will check the documentation. And yes, I'm a beginner for this kind of work. I get the proxies from a csv file, I format them like 'ip:port' then add them to the proxies list. I will add the example of the code as soon as possible.